# Python, не хватает пикселя чёрного

Tags: python

У меня есть график на картинке и получается что там обрыв(чёрного пикселя), как исправить используя интерполяцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import cv2

import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('cropIm.jpg', 0)

kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

img_erosion = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imshow('Input', img)
cv2.imshow('Erosion', img_erosion)
cv2.imshow('Dilation', img_dilation)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Получил:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, сделать морфологическую операцию closing (эрозия+дилатация) - доступно в OpenCV, и, наверное, в Pillow

Comment: спасибо, но на выходе что-то не то получил

Comment: Дилатацию примените не к исходному, а к img_erosion